# Parsing a Swift String to Date, then Components

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, foundation, date-parsing

I have a date "2017-12-31" as a `String`.

What I want to get finally is only the month: "12" as a String.

So I thought that I can change it to `Date` using a date formatter

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM"
```

What do I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to use the `DateFormatter` to create a temporary `Date` object from your source `String` object. Then you have to use it to create your final `String` from the temporary `Date` object.

```
let dateString = "2017-12-31"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

// set the dateFormatter's dateFormat to the dateString's format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

// create date object
guard let tempDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {
    fatalError("wrong dateFormat")
}

// set the dateFormatter's dateFormat to the output format you wish to receive
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LL" // LL is the stand-alone month

let month = dateFormatter.string(from: tempDate)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let dateString = "2017-12-31"    
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.iso8601)    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:  TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent.identifier)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
let localDate = formatter.date(from: dateString) 
formatter.dateFormat = "MM" 
let strMonth = formatter.string(from: localDate!)
print("Month is:",strMonth)
```

Another way

```
let dateString = "2017-12-31"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let localDate = formatter.date(from: dateString)
let month = String(NSCalendar.current.component(.month, from: localDate!))
print(month)
```

Comment: the current timezone it is used by the default so it is not needed. Btw why not simply `formatter.timeZone = .autoupdatingCurrent`. And don't force unwrap your date. It would crash the app in case of an invalid date string.

Comment: And Swift 3 or later you should drop the NS and use `Calendar` instead of `NSCalendar`. Note that for stand alone month it is recommended to use `"LL"` instead of `"MM"` https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkYVY.png

Answer (score 2):

Use below function for getting month from string file of date

```
func getMonthFromDateString(strDate: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date = formatter.date(from: strDate) // Convert String File To Date
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM"
        let strMM = formatter.string(from: date!) // Convert date to string
        return strMM
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's working because `yourDate` is wrong... should be `date`... ;)